# True or false: {{∅}} ⊂ {∅,{∅}}

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

***Note: Actually there's no error in the book and the manual. I actually misread it. The answer is of a different question : 
True or False: {0} ⊂ {0}***

This question is from *Discrete Math Book* by Rosen.

> {{∅}} ⊂ {∅,{∅}}

Answer in the manual is:

> This  is false. For one set  to  be  a  proper  subset  of  another,  the  two sets  cannot  be  equal.

How is {{∅}} is equal to the set {∅,{∅}} ? I know the two sets have different cardinal numbers. So they cannot be equal.

Comment: The $\varnothing$ in your set $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$ doesn't seem to contribute to the cardinality.

Comment: @Vim Are you sure?

Comment: If the sets are "equal", then I would expect that each is equivalent to $\varnothing$, otherwise what is the meaning of $\{\varnothing\}$?

Comment: @EugenCovaci Is $\{\varnothing,a\}=\{a\}$ true?

Comment: @Vim No, is not true

Comment: @Vim: either that is a point the author is trying to make, or else it is a significant error... (Or both)

Comment: This is a silly question, but it has happened to me many times before. Are you sure that you're looking at the right answer on the answers key?

Comment: @EugenCovaci I know a bit about set theory, but does that imply that $\{1,2,\emptyset\} \neq \{1,2\}$?

Comment: @molarmass  Right, see Patrick Stevens answer, it explains very well

Comment: FTR in my university classes $\subset$ did not mean "proper." You would need $\subsetneq$ for that.

Comment: @djechlin: I agree that $\subsetneq$ or even $\subsetneqq$ is better for proper inclusion. But the fact is that a lot of people use $\subset$ for proper inclusion. To make matters worse, there are plenty of people who use $\subset$ for improper inclusion, which creates quite a clash. This is why it is always best to use $\subseteq$ and $\subsetneq$ which are entirely unambiguous.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Is $\{ \{ \emptyset \} \}$ a subset of $\{ \emptyset, \{ \emptyset \} \}$?

Well, it's equivalent to asking whether $\{ \emptyset \} \in \{ \emptyset, \{ \emptyset \} \}$.

And it obviously is.

The answer in the manual is extremely wrong, if you've quoted it correctly. $\{ \{ \emptyset \} \}$ is not equal to $\{ \emptyset, \{ \emptyset \} \}$. (More easily read, $\{ 5 \}$ is not equal to $\{ \emptyset, 5 \}$.) It is possible there is a typographical error in the book, or that you've mis-read it, or misunderstood it.

Notice that $\{ \{ \emptyset \} \}$ *is* equal to $\{ \{ \emptyset \}, \{ \emptyset \} \}$, because sets must have distinct elements and we discard duplicates: $\{1, 1 \} = \{ 1 \}$. This is one possible way you might have misread the book, or that the book might have been printed incorrectly.

**Note:** But make sure what the definition of $\subset$ is! Some use $A \subset B$ to mean any subset (i.e., include $A = B$); others use $A \subseteq B$ for this, in which case they use $A \subset B$ if $A \subseteq B$ but $A \ne B$.

Comment: I have just pasted the ans from the manual.

Comment: @ShashiDwivedi: Out of curiosity I checked the book (K. H. Rosen, _Discrete mathematics and its applications_, 6th ed.). In that edition, the one you mention is exercise 8f) from section 2.1: given that the book gives  the answers of the odd-numbered exercises only, are you sure to have checked the right answer?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Bear in mind that exercise numbering can vary wildly between editions and international versions.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Yup.. I was wrong. But I was having doubts on this question. I was confused if I were reasoning correctly for this question. I got it here. Thanks!

Comment: ShashiDwivedi: In case you didn't state the question from the book correctly, you should add a note which clarifies this circumstance. The reader of your question shouldn't get the wrong impression, that the book has a flaw. Regards,

Comment: @MarkusScheuer I have edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: @ShashiDwivedi: Well done! (+1)